# Swift 3 : TableView refresh doesn't work with row action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm using "Accept"swipe action. When I click the swipe button, everything works perfect on web servers, but `tableView` doesn't get update. Actually I'm using `tableView.reloadData()` in `getOnay` function, but it doesn't work.

Interestingly, when I press the swipe action button twice, it removes the row on the `tableView`.

Here is my code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let onay = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Accept") { action, index in
        let ip = editActionsForRowAt.row
        let taskInfo:Task = self.onayArray[ip]

        self.getOnay(id: taskInfo.id, status: "okay")

        self.onayArray.remove(at: index.row)
        self.loadOnaylar(userID: self.onayCode.userId, code: self.onayCode.systemCode)
    }
    onay.backgroundColor = .green

    return [onay]
}
```

Comment: can you share your  loadOnaylar method code?

Comment: basically it's just a josn post code. I can share the loadOnaylar, but the problem is, when I run debugging, this function doesn't work at all in row action onay var. how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You call the function to remove the element from your array (`self.onayArray.remove(at: index.row)`) after you call `getOnay` which you say calls `tableView.reloadData()`. Therefore you are reloading the data before you remove the element from your array. When you do the swipe action a second time, `reloadData` is called, finally updating the previous action's effect.

Therefore change the ordering of the `getOnay` and `remove(at: index.row)` functions:

```
self.onayArray.remove(at: index.row)
self.getOnay(id: taskInfo.id, status: "okay")
```

Comment: it's not working in the onay var and i don't know why.

Comment: @winnervswinner what does your `getOnay(...)` function do?

Comment: this function has get json method in it. after sening a get method, it reloads the tableview.

Comment: @winnervswinner did you implement the `canEditRowAt` tableview delegate method (needs to return `true`/`false` for the rows that you want to have the swipe actions)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to reloadData() in main Queue?

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: it didn't work. I think it's not about the main queue.